# What is it about Firefox that prompts this rude message from Adobe?

Tags: privacy, firefox, browser-support

<sup>From the following URL: https://new.express.adobe.com/unsupported-browser</sup>

***"This browser doesn't play well with others"***

[image]

---

[image]

Oh, okay. I'm sorry Adobe, that a browser that prioritizes user privacy is inconvenient for you. By the way, what exactly are you trying to pull?

From a tech standpoint though, I am curious: What features of Firefox could possibly pose a problem for a large company like Adobe to support? Because I would be honestly surprised if there are actual legitimate technical reasons. It comes across to me like Adobe just can't be bothered for whatever reason, or simply doesn't like Firefox based on principle. I'm hoping somebody can fill me in on what the actual issue is here (if there even is a legit issue). Thanks.

Comment: Questions here are required to be about [operating and managing your own website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions about [software not related to running your website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are best asked over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If you do ask over there, you might want to include the Firefox version, OS, and whether it's mobile versus desktop.